# Should printf("% .0d",0) print a space? printf("%+.0d",0) print a plus?

Tags: c, standards, printf, language-lawyer

glibc's `printf("% .0d",0)` prints a space, and `printf("%+.0d",0)` prints a plus sign, and the glib printf test checks for this behavior. But is it correct? From the standard (7.19.6.1):

> +        The result of a signed conversion always begins with a plus or minus sign. (It begins with a sign only when a negative value is converted if this flag is not specified.)
>
> space If the first character of a signed conversion is not a sign, or if a signed conversion results in no characters, a space is prefixed to the result. If the space and + flags both appear, the space flag is ignored.

However, regarding precision for the `d` specifier:

> The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is **no characters**.

Naturally this "no characters" rule does not preclude padding the field to the requested *width*, but as far as I can tell, the prefixed space or `+` is part of the conversion, and thus subject to the "no characters" rule.

Has this matter ever been clarified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's talking about the basic conversion without modifiers; that's why the modifiers specifically say what they do when the basic conversion produces no characters.

Comment: The general rule is that the result of formatting should be predictable:  numeric conversions follow specific rules (to the extent possible; floating point is inherently difficult to rationalize across CPUs), and modifiers follow very simple additional rules that don't depend on the result of the conversion.